# Inputting rōmaji diacritic marks (macrons)

Tags: discussion, romaji, ime

I don't usually use much rōmaji, but recently I was writing an article which called for using it quite frequently. I found inputting macrons pretty irritating, such as in words like manyōgana, manyōshū, etc. I eventually found that installing a Maori input method was the quickest, but still somewhat annoying as I had to keep switching between Japanese and Maori when I need to type a diacritic mark.

Is there an easier way to type rōmaji macrons from within the Japanese IME?

Comment: I just noticed that the macron vowels look different above. Another reason I need a better way to input them.